# Is there any way/shader for generating 3d heatmap in Unity WebGL?

Tags: unity-game-engine, glsl, shader, unity-webgl

I'm working on a project in Unity-Webgl which encodes temperature sensor values at different positions into a 3d heatmap of the building. I has tried using particle system and a shader to color the particles according to these values but the effect is not very ideal. I am now searching for a solution or shader which could color a semi-transparent object using temperature values (e.g. volumetric lighting with color). It should look like this:[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ge6s.png)

I has searched the internet but only found many volumetric shaders don't support OpenGL or only support single color.

I wonder if there is any other solution. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-create-heatmap-in-unity.423163/

Comment: @BooNonMooN I has also read about it, but it's not quite what i want. But appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a shader to accomplish the effect in your example.  You can load horizontal slices of your heatmap data into textures, and put them on planes.  Here's an example I whipped up that uses perlin noise for the heat data.  You can get the perlin noise function from here https://github.com/keijiro/PerlinNoise

```
public class HeatmapBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int x_size = 128; //width of the textures
    public int y_size = 128; //height of the textures
    public int num_shells = 10; //number of slices of the data
    public GameObject plane_prefab; //the slice geometry and shader
                                    //this prefab is just a plane with the same area 
                                    //as the building, with a material that has its
                                    //shader set to Unlit/Transparent

    public float height = 10; //how tall in world units the dataset is
    public Color LowColor; //the cold color
    public Color HiColor; //the hot color

    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num_shells; i++)
        {

            var shell = GameObject.Instantiate(this.plane_prefab);  //create a slice
            shell.transform.parent = this.transform;
            shell.transform.position += new Vector3(0, (float)i / (float)this.num_shells * this.height, 0);

            var texture = new Texture2D(x_size, y_size);
            //for each texel in the shell's texture
            for(int x = 0; x < x_size; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < y_size; y++)
                {
                    var heatLocation = new Vector3((float)x / (float)x_size, (float)y / (float)y_size, (float)i / (float)num_shells); //find the coordinate in the heatmap for this texel
                    var heat = (Perlin.Fbm(heatLocation, 4) + 1)/2f; //grab the heat map data
                    texture.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Lerp(this.LowColor, this.HiColor, heat)); //interpolate the color based on heat map
                }
            }

            texture.Apply();


            shell.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.SetTexture("_MainTex", texture);

        }
    }
}
```

If you want to interactively fly around in the scene inside the building, the solution will be more complex.  You will need to align the shells with the camera, calculate how big they need to be based on the cameras view frustum, and sample your heatmap data based on the rotated orientations of the shells.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! It helps a lot. I has tried it in a demo and the effect looks quiet ideal. But I got some `GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION` errors in WebGL. I am wondering if you have any idea.

Comment: Strangely it works in the actual project, I must have done something wrong.